# Smart contract size limit

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

Need your help/suggestion for below question

**Question: Smart contract size limit**

My application size for Smart (contracts folder with .sol file) is around 140 KB
It is structured as below, with each module folders will have their specific .sol file
e.g., Module 1 till Module 5

Module 1 (Folder): below is the content inside
interfaces1.sol - 2 KB
implementation1.sol - 26 KB
library1.sol - 4 KB
proxy1.sol - 1 KB

Module 2 (Folder): below is the content inside
interfaces2.sol - 3 KB
implementation2.sol - 28 KB
library2.sol - 5 KB
proxy2.sol - 1 KB

When I will compile & deploy the Smart Contract of whole application
which is spread across folders i.e., Module 1 till Module 5

How the Smart Contract size will be calculated

1. It is calculated for .sol file or the generated bytecode file?
2. It is calculated per/individual each .sol file (e.g., implementation1.sol) spread across folders or?
3. It is calculated the overall size i.e., Module 1 till Module 5?
4. What is the Smart Contract size limit for deploying to Main network
5. What is the Smart Contract size limit for deploying to Test network (Kovan, Rinkeby, Ropsten)
6. What will happen if I go ahead with existing size of 140 KB and deploy the Smart Contract to Test network, Main Network, will it allow?
7. Any solution to solve/reduce the current Smart Contract size (e.g., splitting implementation1.sol & implementation2.sol to multiple .sol file)?
8. If I split single (implementation2.sol) file to multiple (implementation2_1.sol & implementation2_2.sol) file, and some state variables & mapping I declare in implementation2_1.sol file, how can I access/use them in implementation2_2.sol file, what will happen to storage in this case ?

Your quick response will really help as I am stuck with this problem & need to resolve it soon

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please share ur insights,it will help others